# logout from profile python

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

How to make correct logout from user account. Login code is working well, but I always have to type email and password to get access to my account. How to make sure that when I open the site I can be already on my account?

Code:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'GET' and 'loggedin' in session:
        return redirect(url_for('profile'))

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['password']

        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM users.data WHERE email = %s AND password = %s',
                    (email, password))
        account = cur.fetchone()
        if account:
            session['loggedin'] = True
            session['id'] = account[0]
            session['firstname'] = account[1]
            session['email'] = account[3]
            return redirect(url_for('profile'))
        else:
            return render_template('error.html')

    return render_template('login.html')
```

`#profile method`

```
@app.route('/profile', methods=['GET'])
def profile():
    if request.method == 'GET' and 'loggedin' in session:
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT firstname, lastname, email FROM users.data WHERE description = 'description'")
        account = cur.fetchall()
        description = account
        return render_template('profile.html', id=session['id'], firstname=session['firstname],email=session['email'], description=description)
```

`#logout method`

```
@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    if session.pop('email', None):
        print('Logout successfully!')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

`profile.html`

```
<h2 class="white-text">Welcome, {{ firstname }}</h2>

{% if session.email %}
<button class="btn btn-primary">
  <a href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">
      Logout
  </a>
</button>
{% endif %}
```

When I press `logout` button, I get this error: `KeyError: 'firstname'`. What is the problem?

Comment: The error comes from which line ?

Comment: @azro from this line `return render_template('profile.html', id=session['id'], firstname=session['firstname],email=session['email'], description=description)`

Comment: You have to remove `loggedin` fmo session too, Because you go into the method `login` and its in first if as it's GET and loggedin has not been removed. So it goes into `profile` method and here it seems that firstname is not present

Comment: @azro, I have removed `logged in session` and now I can logged out successfully, but when I login and close and reopen page I still need to type login and password. Could you please help me to solve this?

Comment: Don't know where the problem is, print(session) at different place to see why you don't go in the good if branches